# What is the difference between (.*?) and (.*)? in regex?

Tags: regex

For regular expressions, what is the difference between `(.*?)` and `(.*)?`?

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1123708/capturing-zero-or-more-characters-in-regex-while-being-non-greedy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the regex tester at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) (no affiliation) to test these.

`(.*?)` matches any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`), as few times as possible to make the regex match (`?`). You'll get a match on any string, but you'll only capture a blank string because of the question mark. This feature is much more useful when you have a more complicated regex. Here, the parser doesn't have to capture anything at all to get a match: the asterisk allows any number of characters in the capturing group, while the question mark makes the parser save as many as possible from the input text for later, resulting in nothing being captured.

`(.*)?` captures a group zero or one times (`?`). That group consists of a run of any length (`*`) of any character (`.`). This also will match anything, but it will capture the first line, since the dot matches anything except a newline.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  In an effort to simply my question, I oversimplified.  But your answer is useful and informative, so I won't change this question (I'll post another one).  Your answer brings up an interesting regex tidbit: can you add to your answer *why* only a blank string is captured by the first expression?

Comment: Since adding more info to my question would have nullified your answer (and I want to respect the effort you placed in writing your answer), I composed a new question with more details.  It's still a bit simplified (no one will read a 2 page question!), but I hope I provided sufficient context: https://superuser.com/questions/1123708/capturing-zero-or-more-characters-in-regex-while-being-non-greedy

Answer (score 1):

To exemplify the difference between `(.*)?` and `(.*?)` a little bit:

First what is `.*`?

`.*` means any type of character (the dot) of any amount, also 0, i.e. no character is also possible.

**(.*)?**

You can think of it as something that captures a variable text that is in the middle of a certain text:

So e.g. there is a program that examines log messages to see if there is something specific in them ([fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)).

```
failregex = ^[Ll]ogin attempt for nonexistent user ('.*')? from 192.168.1.20
```

Captures the usernames e.g. at this point.

If you look at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) with the following examples perhaps this becomes a little clearer:

[image: nothing]
[image: nothing2]
[image: fit]

And because `?` at this point is so called *greedy* it captures as much as possible - or in other words: The last `inbetween` splits if multiple `inbetween` would have been before.

[image: multiple splits]

**(.*?)**

Here the `?` makes it *ungreedy*.
Meaning if you have something like

```
WORD1 bla2 WORD2 bla3 WORD2
```

`WORD1(.*?)WORD2` only takes it to the first `WORD2`

[image: ungreedy]

whereas
`WORD1(.*)WORD2` is greedy an goes until the last occurrence of `WORD2`

[image: greedy]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. “what is the difference between `(.*?)` and `(.*)?`?”

Comment: Yes. I'll try to complement it.