# Capturing zero or more characters in regex while being non-greedy

Tags: regex

For regular expressions, it is often desirable to make part of the expression non-greedy.  For this, we use the question mark.

What is the difference between `(.*?)` and `(.*)?` when used as part of a larger expression in order to capture zero or more characters?

For example, will:
`(.*?)ng` ever yield a different result than `(.*)?ng` ?

The end results are the same (confirmed by https://regex101.com/), but are there differences that are not so obvious?

Comment: Use `angng` for the test string at [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to see how the two expressions match different parts of the string.

Comment: @creidhne Thanks so much.  So `(.*)?ng` is the proper expression. It's what I've always used (and makes more sense), but I was reading a book that used `(.*?)ng`, and it just looked wrong, but I was having trouble putting my finger on *why*.  Your example illustrates it quite well.  Besides cases where the terminating expression (`ng` in this example) is duplicated, can you think of other cases where the results will be different?

Comment: So are you going to close the loop and post an answer?  :-)  BTW, the first question showed up in the review queue as a dupe of this one (which is surprising, since you can't usually name a question as the primary if it doesn't have an answer), but the action doesn't yet have any votes.  Linking them would make more sense if this one has its own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [my other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1123703/380318), the `.*?` version is lazy. That means it will make the parenthesized part apply to as little as possible for the regex to match. The version with the question mark outside the parentheses is greedy: it will apply to as many characters as possible.

Both expressions will have the same effect if you only look at getting a match versus not. The two wildcard runs will get a match *if possible*, but one minimizes the captured amount while the other maximizes it. They differ, however, in what they capture.

Let's see an example of the capturing differences: `singing`. It contains the literal `ng` twice. In `(.*?)ng`, `(.*?)` will grab everything up until the first `ng` - once it sees that, it's done: it's lazy. It will capture **`si`** in this case. `(.*)?ng` will try to capture as much as possible - it's greedy - leaving only the final `ng` out. It captures **`singi`** here.

Unless there are multiple instances of the part outside the wildcard run in the input string, you won't see a difference.